# what are the different sizes of copper pipe for gas or water

Tags: pipe, copper

I'mcurrently fixing a water leak under the house and cant find SharkBite, coupling, or anything to fit.  Could the copper pipe under the house be gas pipe used as water pipe.  It is about an eighth of inch larger in diameter.

Comment: Copper is virtually never used for gas, as soldering is not an option around flammable contents. Are you sure the line is copper? How old is the house and where are you located?

Comment: @ShimonRura: All the gas piping in every house I have ever owned has been copper.  I have just moved into a house built in 2017 - all the gas piping is copper.

Comment: Gas piping that is copper may use the soft type of copper tubing that is then flared on the ends with specialty tools and uses fittings specific to the flared tubing connections.